# How can I start emacsclient then eval a lisp expression but with emacsclient window opened?

Tags: intellij-idea, emacs

Example: `emacsclient --socket-name ~/.emacs.d/server/server -eval "(message \"argsFromCommandLine\")"`

If I execute command above, the emacsclient will print `ok` then just exit.
I want to eval a lisp expression after emacsclient start but with new emacsclient window opened.

Actually, I want to execute this command from Intellij with external tools.
`emacsclient --socket-name ~/.emacs.d/server/server -eval "(magit-status \"/Users/louxiu/projects/magit-test-project\")"`, jump from one source file of magit-test-project to its magit-status-mode in emacsclient.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing `-c/--create-frame` to `emacsclient` should do the trick.

If I run `emacsclient -c --eval "(magit-status \"/path/to/project\")"` I end up with a new emacs frame in a `magit-status` buffer for the expected project.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Actually the previous command works, but the window doesn't switch from intellij to emacs. Of course, this should be another question.